# Mean hitting times with 2 absorbing states.

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

Let the transition matrix be:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 0\\\ 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0& 0& 0 \\\ 1/2 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1/2& 0 \\\ 0 & 1/2 & 0& 0& 0& 1/2 \\\ 0 & 0& 0& 1/2 & 0& 1/2 \\\ 0 & 0& 0& 0& 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Given you start at $P_2$ (the second column) find the mean hitting times.

I have tried to do this by marginalisation, but I am unsure on how to actually apply this here, given there are 2 absorbing states. Is it right to write out all of the mean stopping time, e.g. $MST_{P{_{2, 1000}}} $ = $1+1/2$    $MST_{P{_{5, 1000}}} $ and then do the same the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally clear about your notation but you can say something like

- $MST_1=0$
- $MST_2=1+ \frac12MST_1+\frac12MST_3$
- $MST_3=1+ \frac12MST_1+\frac12MST_5$
- $MST_4=1+ \frac12MST_2+\frac12MST_6$
- $MST_5=1+ \frac12MST_4+\frac12MST_6$
- $MST_6=0$

which are six equations in six unknowns and easily solvable by substitution

Comment: Solving these, all of the mean stopping times are 2 of course, but that seems a bit low to me. Perhaps not though.

Comment: If you reduce the problem to (a) staying in states 2,3,4 or 5 with probability $\frac12$ or (b) moving to states 1 or 6 and stopping with probability $\frac12$, then the number of steps is a geometric random variable on the positive integers with mean $2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** There is a positive probability that the walk goes from state 2 immediately to state 1 (an absorbing state) while never visiting any other. Similarly, there is a positive probability that the walk goes from state 2 to 3 to 5 to 6 (the other absorbing state) while never visiting any other.

Thus: for any state $x$, there is a positive probability that the walk never travels from state 2 to $x$. What does that imply about the hitting times?

Comment: That they're infinite. But the question asks what is the expected amount of gambles and something in me says that the answer wouldn't be infinity as that could be a bit of a "trick"

Comment: Ah -- that changes my interpretation of what the question is asking. Usually "hitting time" refers to a single state (in my experience at least), but here I think it refers to the hitting time of the union of states 1 and 6 (the graveyard states). In that case, you could easily edit the Markov chain to collapse those two states down to one; after all, all you care about is how long it takes to get to one of them, and once the chain visits one of them it never leaves.